# How to update shim-signed to the latest version in linux mint system?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
base-files : Conflict: base-files:i386
base-files:i386 : Conflict: base-files
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve failed, probably due to a package being asked to stay current.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cW9Kg.png)

I tried uninstalling it and reinstalling it failed, it's a must system software

Comment: See https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=391816